# Use Regexp to match a certain repetitive pattern string input in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I would like to check if an input matches a specific repetitive pattern.

Pattern = **3 Uppercase character follow by 2 digits and being separated by ':'**

I have try the below regexp but it is not working.

```
# This should return "Input Criteria Meet"
set user_input_1 "AAB22:GHD23:UDJ29:YUD51"

if {[regexp {^[[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}:]+$} $user_input_1]} {
    puts "Input Criteria Meet"
} else {
    puts "Input Criteria not meet"
}
```

Comment: Try `^(?:[A-Z]{3}\d{2}:)*[A-Z]{3}\d{2}$`. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/x9KHE9/2/). Move your cursor across the regex at the link to object a description of each regex token.

Comment: Have you figured out the big issue with your original RE yet?

Answer (score 3):

How about this? Assuming you have 4 parts, otherwise replace `{4}` with `+`.

```
^([A-Z]{3}\d{2}(:|$)){4}\b
```

Explanation:

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Start of capture group
- `[A-Z]{3}` Three uppercase characters
- `\d{2}` Two digit characters
- `(` Start of OR capture group

  - `:|$` Colon character OR end of string
- `)` End of OR capture group
- `{4}` Four instances of the preceeding capture group
- `\b` Word boundary to prevent a trailing `:` to be matched.

Comment: Colon is not a special character: it does not need to be escaped.

Comment: This allows a `:` at the end of the string, and we've not been told the actual criteria for the number of parts so it's best to not bake that in.

Comment: @glennjackman yeah not sure why I escaped that although harmless.

Comment: @DonalFellows that has been fixed with \b. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}(?::[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}){3}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}` Match 3 times A-Z and 2 times a digit 0-9
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `:[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}` Match `:` 3 times A-Z and 2 times a digit 0-9
- `){3}` Close non capture group and repeat 3 times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5wluxb/1)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier to not use a regular expression for everything, and to instead use one in concert with another operation. Some types of validation are also much clearer when put in a helper procedure:

```
proc ValidateString {input} {
    foreach part [split $input ":"] {
        # A regular expression is the easiest way of validating the interior pieces
        if {![regexp {^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}$} $part]} {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

set user_input_1 "AAB22:GHD23:UDJ29:YUD51"
if {[ValidateString $user_input_1]} {
    puts "Input Criteria Meet"
} else {
    puts "Input Criteria not meet"
}
```

You *could* instead use a more complex RE like this:

```
# ...
if {[regexp {^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}(:[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2})*$} $user_input_1]} {
    # ...
```

but that's significantly harder to read unless you switch to extended form, and lacks the clearer mnemonics of a named helper procedure so I wouldn't really recommend it.

Comment: Instead of using a `foreach` loop, you can also use `lsearch` to check if there isn't any part that doesn't meet the criterion: `if {[lsearch -not -regexp [split $user_input_1 :] {^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}$}] < 0} {# ...`

Answer (score -1):

I have tried out the following and it is working.

```
regexp {^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}(:[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2})+$} $user_input_1
```